# How to copy all the files that do not exist in a directory in Linux?

Tags: linux

Is there a way to copy all the files and subdirectories from one directory to another that are not already there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is copy with a no clobber option, which will skip the file if it is already there:

```
cp -nr /some/directory /some/backup directory
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cp -r /home/hope/files/* /home/hope/backup
```

The first line with /home is the location of files you want to copy and the second is the destination where do you want to copy.

More here: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000838.htm

Best Regards

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.  Since the Linux command is only one line, why not add it to your answer?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: will this override the existing files?

Comment: Yes, it will override if the same file exists in the location.